# Windows 7 freezes about a minute after login

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze

I have an HP laptop and when I boot it up It has a black screen.  So I quit explorer.exe and start it up again.  That makes the desktop come back but then it freezes and I have to do a hard reset.  It also will freeze even if I just leave it on the black screen.  Things I have tried:

- Booting into safe mode (doesn't freeze)
- Booting a linux USB drive (doesn't freeze)
- Doing the Windows 7 startup repair (doesn't work)
- Doing a system restore on several points (sometimes it says it works, sometimes it says it fails. I can tell if it works or not but it still freezes)
- Using Avast boot time scan ( a few things found but still freezes)
- Using CHKDSK (It deleted some index entries and recovered orphaned files)

I don't know what else to try besides a fresh install but I don't wanna lose my data.

Comment: If it runs fine in Safe Mode, then it's probably a program or utility running in the background of Normal Mode that's causing it.  Use MSConfig to deselect all 3rd party start-ups, and then re-enable them, one at a time, until you find the culprit. If you're worried about losing your data while working on it, make a backup.

Answer (score -1):

I would seriously try to scan the laptop with Malware Bytes Anti-Malware first...

Then I would look to see if there is something causing a conflict - i.e grafic-card, sounds-cart etc...

Eliminate the possible chances of malware first - then debug it to see if there are something causing this conflict..

If those two suggestions don't work it's time to look at the settings for the harddrive and also run some test on this one.

But believe me...Malware Bytes Anti-Malware can do magic;)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also ran malware bytes in safe mode.  I also just did a clean boot with only the bare minimum running and It seems to be working fine. What would be the best way to determine which service / driver is causing the issue?

Comment: unplug / remove any devices connected to your laptop, check the event logs